# Delete NSManagedObject from managedObjectContext & tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I have a `UITableView` that displays attributes of entities that are in an `array` created with an `NSFetchRequest`. My instructor tells me for my purposes, I **do NOT need a `fetchedResultsController`**--so **I do NOT need to add `NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate`** methods to my `UITableViewController` class. His analogy was putting a Porsche engine in a VW Beetle.

My tableView has 2 sections (0 and 1). Everything works fine until I try to delete objects from section 1 (section 0 is static).

With this commitEditingStyle code, the app crashes with his error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], 
/SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3347.40/UITableView.m:1623

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete && indexPath.section == 1) {
        // Delete cell
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];


        // Delete LocationCategory from managedObjectContext
        LocationCategory *categoryToDelete = [self.locationCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:categoryToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

When I restart the app, the `locationCategory` (my `NSManagedObject`) is no longer in the `managedObjectContext`. I know I've got a problem updating the `tableView`, but I don't know how to resolve it. I've dug around, tried a bunch of prospective solutions, but nothing resolves the crashing.

Here's how my array is created:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    self.title = @"Select a Category";

    // Core Data
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    self.managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    // Fetch LocationCategories & dump them in an array
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"LocationCategory" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"categoryName" ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:&sortDescriptor count:1];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSArray *categories = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    self.locationCategories = categories;

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

**Update:**

Here's what the code looked like at the end when it worked:

```
// This was previously an NSArray. It needs to be an NSMutableArray
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *locationCategories;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete && indexPath.section == 1) {
        // Delete LocationCategory from managedObjectContext
        LocationCategory *categoryToDelete = [self.locationCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:categoryToDelete];
        [self.locationCategories removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];


        // Delete cell
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView endUpdates];

    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try to change the order? first deleting and saving and the `[tableView beginUpdates]`

Comment: Just tried reversing the order of the stuff deleted. `managedObjectContext` stuff first, then the `tableView` without luck. I also tried putting `[tableView beginUpdates]` first in the method and `[tableView endUpdates]` at the end of the method (outside the `if` statement). I crash with the same error at `[tableView endUpdates]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably your tableView datasource methods use `self.locationCaregories`.  If so, the problem is that you don't remove the relevant `Category` from that array (although you delete it from the managedObjectContext, it remains in the array).

Now, because `self.locationCategories` is an NSArray, it is **immutable**, so you can't just remove the relevant item.  You could reperform the fetch immediately after you delete the object, but that seems a bit inefficient.  I recommend instead that you make `self.locationCategories` an NSMutableArray.  You will need to amend the property definition, and also the line in `viewWillAppear` where you first set it:

```
    NSArray *categories = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
    self.locationCategories = [categories mutableCopy];
```

Then in the `commitEditingStyle` method, you can remove the relevant object from the array:

```
    LocationCategory *categoryToDelete = [self.locationCategories objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.locationCategories removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

And as thorb65 says, move the code to delete the rows to the end of the method - you should get the data right, before you update the table.

Comment: Thank you @thorb65 and @pbasdf for your replies. Between your answers, I got this thing working. I think the `NSArray` was part of the problem. The solutions mentioned here didn't get it working on their own, but out of desperation I took some of the code from `viewWillAppear` and recreated `self.locationCategories` after the item was deleted from the `managedObjectContext`. Thank you both for your help on this.

Comment: Re-read and updated code as @pbasdf described--much cleaner & much shorter. Thank you again!